# "'X` may be uninitialized in this function" warning and pthread, C

Tags: c, pthreads, warnings

The code below produces the following warning: 
`‘factoryThread’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]`

```
    pthread_t factoryThreads[NUM_FACTORIES];
    int factoryNums[NUM_FACTORIES];
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_FACTORIES; i++) {
        factoryNums[i] = i + 1;
        pthread_t factoryThread;
        factoryThreads[i] = factoryThread;
        pthread_create(&factoryThreads[i], NULL, createAndInsertCandy,
                &factoryNums[i]);
    }
```

The code seems to work as expected, but I'm still curious as to what is causing the warning and what I can do to fix it.

Comment: pthread_t factoryThread;   factoryThreads[i] = factoryThread;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You invoked *undefined behavior* by using value of uninitialized variable having automatic storage duration, which is indeterminate, and it just *happened* to work.

Remove the meaningless variable and assignment.

```
pthread_t factoryThreads[NUM_FACTORIES];
int factoryNums[NUM_FACTORIES];
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_FACTORIES; i++) {
    factoryNums[i] = i + 1;
    pthread_create(&factoryThreads[i], NULL, createAndInsertCandy,
            &factoryNums[i]);
}
```

Comment: What is "automatic storage duration"? Do you mean it goes out of scope when the function it is created in returns? That code is in my `main()` function, so the threads don't go out of scope until the end of the program. Is there still an issue (the factory threads all finish before `main()` does)?

Comment: No, `factoryThread` is a local variable in the block and it will vanish after exiting the `for` loop. The problem in this case is not that they vanish but that uninitialized non-static local variables have indeterminate variables, and you used it, which is bad.

Comment: Then the `factoryThread` objects in the revised code are presumably initialized within `pthread_create()`?

Comment: This may be beyond the scope of a comments section, but do you think I should put the `pthread_create()` in an if block to check if the creation is succesful? More generally, using POSIX threads involves quite a few calls to `pthread_...` functions. Should they all be embedded in an if block?